# Problema con función count en php

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo llamado `class.Database.php` el cual contiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php

class Database
{   
    private static $db_host     = "localhost";
    private static $db_user     = "root";
    private static $db_password = "123";
    private static $db_database = "colegio_prevenlameze";

    static function select($query)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
        //$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        if(isset($result->num_rows))
        {
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $rows = self::resultToArray($result);
                $result->free();
                $mysqli->close();
                return $rows;
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

Y tengo otro archivo llamado prueba.php que contiene el siguiente código:

```
<?php
include_once("class.Database.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE matricula = 'ADM939984' AND password = 'xjcf87f09'"; 

$personas = Database::select($query);

echo "Total de usuarios ".count($personas);
?>
```

La consulta arroja ceros registros porque en la base de datos no hay un usuario registrado con esa matricula.

El problema aquí es que la función count me esta devolviendo 1, cuando que debería devolver 0, como puedo solucionar esto??

Comment: veo mas bien un error rebuscado!!... por que ya hiciste verificastes si es vacio,debes hacer dos if, o devolver un row vacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como es evidente, [`count`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) tiene que aplicarse a algo que se pueda contar, por ejemplo un array.

Si tú pruebas este código:

```
$ok=FALSE;
echo count($ok).PHP_EOL;
$ok=TRUE;
echo count($ok).PHP_EOL;
$ok=10;
echo count($ok);
```

**El resultado será siempre `1`.**

Si observas tu función, pase lo que pase, siempre devuelve `FALSE`, porque es lo último que tienes en ella.

**<s>`return FALSE;`</s>**

Y contar un `FALSE` o cualquier cosa que no sea contable, te devolverá siempre uno, a no ser que esa variable no exista y entonces tendrás un `0`.

### Solución:

- Declarar al principio del código la variable `$rows` como un array vacío, el cual cambiará solamente si se cumple la condición y al final de la función hacer el `return` de la variable. Entonces podrás contarla adecuadamente al recibirla.
- Cambiar el primer `if` por esto: `if($result)`, así estarás evaluando que la consulta a la BD se realizó adecuadamente.

Propuesta de código:

```
<?php

class Database
{   
    private static $db_host     = "localhost";
    private static $db_user     = "root";
    private static $db_password = "123";
    private static $db_database = "colegio_prevenlameze";

    static function select($query)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(self::$db_host, self::$db_user, self::$db_password, self::$db_database);
        //$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        $rows=array();
        if($result)
        {
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                $rows = self::resultToArray($result);
                $result->free();
                //$mysqli->close();
                //return $rows;
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
        return $rows;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu solucion, me ha salvado el dia

Comment: De nada @Alex. He editado de nuevo. El `$mysqli->close();` sobra dentro del segundo `if`, ya que no harás ningún `return` ahí dentro, sólo es necesario el `close` que está antes del único return que quedará en la función.

Answer (score 0):

Eso ocurre porque false cuenta como 1, dado que la documentación pide un array o un objeto contable, y un booleano es un objeto contable, false pero objeto al fin de cuentas. si quieres que te regrese 0 como tal, puedes hacer el return como `[]` o regresarlo como `NULL`;

http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php